# How can I use javascript or css for making a div highlighted and the rest of the content is gray or shadowed?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, html

I see divs act like active boxes and I thought there must be a way for it, rather than adjusting color of the page or creating a layer and bringing the focused div to the front using z index.

I want to shadow everything on the page, except for the div I want to show to the user.
Like facebooks shows the pictures in front but you can still see the page with some 50% opacity in the background.

Comment: ok then, what have you tried?

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you wnat?

Comment: Can you do this?  Yes.  Should you?  No, it would be very slow.  Consider altering your UI design

Comment: I voted to close because this question is too broad and shows no research effort. You could simply inspect any of those "highlighted divs" you saw to see how they were built. After that, you could still come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an element to cover the entire page:

```
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Style it:

```
#modal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Only show it when you need to. Next create a class for elements we want above this:

```
.overModal {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/pVUHP/

Comment: You did the homework instead of the OP, but I still have to +1 :). It is left to the OP to look up browser support for `rgba()`.

Comment: @bažmegakapa SO is here to give answers. At times somebody might come to SO because they're on a time-crunch and need help quick. If they love the profession, they will learn from the answers. If not, the answer exists for hundreds of other people who will take the time to study it.

Comment: I thought there might be one single css property for this, like css 3, my intention was not making somebody to write code for me. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I would use `background: #888;` and `opacity: .8;` instead.